# Error 324 only while uploading in my Website

Tags: php

I am working on a site and want to add a classified directory to it.

But the installing required upgrading of the php version. After that I am unable to upload contents especially images, even in classified and other sites which are under the same hosting are not working.

Please let me know whether it is a problem with php version or a problem with the hosting. Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Related SU:SE: [What is error 324? Is it related to Google Chrome? Or Verizon Webmail?](http://superuser.com/questions/99792/what-is-error-324-is-it-related-to-google-chrome-or-verizon-webmail). If it's happening to other sites with the same hosting provider - i'm inclined to believe it's an issue with them rather than you. You should talk to them about it.

Comment: This error has been noted as related to the amount of memory that PHP is allowed. Do you know how much memory your hosting Co allow a PHP script to use?

Comment: Please help me know from where i can see this. Is it available in php configurations?

Comment: When i am using a script to upload image then i get this error only. i.e. net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: All the scripts were working properly and i have also uploaded a number of fields. I also tried modifying the max_execution_time.

Comment: I changed the memory_limit from 128M to 512M. But still its not working.